# Cast full OS X screen on RPI

Tags: macos, osmc

I have a RPI w/ OSMC built-in installed, but I keep tweaking the Debian background for my purposes :).

I am trying to stream my MacBook on the TV (HDMI), for instance for dual-screening, but after several unsuccessful Internet searches, I cannot find pre-cooked solutions. With VLC and HTTP Streaming, the result has poor performances : a huge time offset, no sound yet, bad resolution, bad image rate.

Do you have an idea to do well ?
Thank you !